# how to avoid asp page reload after pressing enter in input

Tags: jquery, asp.net, input

I try to catch the Enter key in an input field (actually bar code input) to un-hide a button. This is for our workflow: first enter a number, then show some buttons to proceed. Looks simple, but I just don't get it to work. When pressing Enter, the page seems to load again, which is just visible in firebug. The button gets visible for a very short time and the reload re-initialize it to the hidden state.

This is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_Head" runat="Server">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // initialize with invisible borders
        _Quant_notQuali = null;
        QuantQuali_SetBorders();
        $('div#quantqual').hide();
        $('input#barcode').val('');
        $('input#barcode').keyup(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                $('div#quantqual').show();
            }
            return false;
        });
        return;
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder_Body" runat="Server">
<div>
    Barcode:
    <input id="barcode" type="text" style="font-size: larger;" />
</div>
<div id="quantqual">
    <div class="button" id="quant" onclick="_Quant_notQuali = true; QuantQuali_SetBorders();">Kwantitatief</div>
    <div class="button" id="quali" onclick="_Quant_notQuali = false; QuantQuali_SetBorders();">Kwalitatief</div>
</div>
```

Why does the page reload after pressing / catching Enter? Or perhaps after `show()`?

Might this be because of interaction with the ASP system? (or the MasterPage?) The `input` element does not have `runat=server`, because data will be sent later to the server with some ajax call.

I am at a total loss here ...

Comment: You have any submit button on your page?

Comment: No, but the ASP system might insert one? I did not write one, and in FireBug I do not see one, but after all, the ASP page is a form.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: tried this, did not help :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. How a good night of sleep can help :-)

First, the Submit was not caused by an `<input type=submit/>` element, because there isn't one. The Submit was caused by the `action` attribute in the `<form>` element of the ASP page. I tested this with this simple html page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="page.aspx">
        <div>
            Barcode: <input id="barcode" type="text" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As soon as you hit Enter, the page tries to load page.aspx.

Funny enough, if you add the usual Submit button, hitting Enter in the input text field does nothing. This would be one solution to my problem.

Most projects have a Submit button, and if you then want to use the Enter key in, say, a password input text field to load the action page, you need extra JS, as described in [this article](http://www.barattalo.it/javascript/how-to-capture-enter-key-pressed-in-a-form-javascript/)

Second, `e.preventDefault();` should not be done on the `<input>` element, but on the entire window. Adding this, found in that article, to the above code fixed the problem:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ...
        // prevent Submit when pressing Enter key
        $(window).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input#barcode').keyup(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                //Add this
                e.returnValue=false;
                e.cancel = true;

                $('div#quantqual').show();
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Comment: Can you post more of the HTML?

Comment: I edited my solution, try that. When you make your comparsion maybe don't evaluate the type, just check its equal. Doubt that's the issue, but could be.

Comment: Did not work :-( Must go home now, tomorrow I will try the JS in a regular html non-asp page. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with `<button type="button>` elements with jQuery click handlers causing page refresh. Try adding an e.preventDefault() within the keyup() handler.

```
$('input#barcode').keyup(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        $('div#quantqual').show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Try adding a .change() event handler to the `input#barcode` with parameter representing the DOM event. Add a preventDefault() there as well. This would be prior to executing the `.val('')` value change.

Comment: As a test replace the code inside the `keyup()` handler callback with just `return false;` and see if still refreshes.

Comment: i tried both suggestions, did not help. Still reloads.

Comment: You may need examine `QuantQuali_SetBorders();` and determine if it's setting some kind of event handlers. Also, as you mentioned in your question, if your master page or parent template has handlers. Those may need `return false;` or `preventDefault()`/`stopPropogation()` applied.

Comment: The masterpage is pretty empty, has only an `asp:LoginView` control. Besides, looking a View Source, or Firebug, I should see all html of the page, and there is no submit in view. Still I agree that somewhere ASP may need a submit